# Programmatically instantiating ValueExpressions

Tags: jsf, dynamic, components, el

I am dynamically adding components on PreRenderViewEvent, using the following method http://blog.kennardconsulting.com/2010/10/safely-manipulating-component-tree-with.html .

It works fine for the component adding part, but I have a problem when I try to dynamically instantiate ValueExpression-s.

To be more specific, I have a problem when I try to forge a dynamic ValueExpression using a dynamically passed parameter.

Let's try to explain an example...

At the top level, I use a tag component (a component described in a tag file, *not* a composite and *not* a custom component.

```
<my:topComponent param=#{toto}"/>
```

In my:topComponent, I pass param to a nested component.

```
<my:nestedComponent param2=#{param}/>
```

This nestedComponent is using a custom component (in my case, a component I derive from primefaces Datatable), passing it param2 as another parameter...

```
<my:customComponent finalParam=#{param2}/>
```

In customComponent, I dynamically add some child components on PreRenderViewEvent and set some ValueExpression-s for customComponent.

Some of those expressions use finalParam. So, I unwrap finalParam value, then build a new ValueExpression :

```
String varName = getValueExpression("finalParam").getExpressionString().replace("#{", "").replace("}", "");
```

Then I instantiate my dynamic value expression using this helper function :

```
public static ValueExpression createValueExpression(String expression, Class clazz) {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ELContext elContext = fc.getELContext();
        ExpressionFactory expFactory = fc.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
        ValueExpression ret = expFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, expression, clazz);
        return ret;
    }
```

Example :

```
ValueExpression dynExpression = JSFUtils.createValueExpression("#{" + varName + ".code" + "}"), Object.class);
```

In this example, the value expression is "#{param2.code}"

I can then set this valueExpression to my component :

```
this.setValueExpression("rowKey", dynExpression);
```

All this code is in the custom component class. I use the renderer of the base class.

However, the programmatically instantiated ValueExpression is not properly evaluated during rendering. For instance, when primefaces datatable renderer tries to compute the rowKey, #{param2.code} is evaluated to "null", as param2 seems to be unknown.

What should I do to correct this ? While debugging, I noticed that the getValueExpression("finalParam") has a VariableMapper set, while dynExpression has none (null value)

If I get it right, this VariableMapper is used to translate param2 to param.

How can I instantiate my dynamic expression so that the VariableMapper(s) chain is preserved ? The question is the same for FunctionMapper.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
I agree with Richard Kennard reply : it seems to be the same bug.

As I can not wait years for a fix, I use the following kludge to recursively resolve variables. It works for simple cases with my MyFaces 2.1.9 / CODI 1.0.5 / OWB 1.1.6 / Tomcat 7 stack.

```
    public static String getValueExpressionExpression(ValueExpression valueExpression) {
        return valueExpression.getExpressionString().replace("#{", "").replace("}", "");
    }

    public static String getMappedValueExpression(ValueExpression valueExpression) {
        ContextAwareTagValueExpression ctxAware = (ContextAwareTagValueExpression)valueExpression;
        if(ctxAware != null) {
            return getMappedValueExpression((WrappedValueExpression)ctxAware.getWrapped());
        }
        return getValueExpressionExpression(valueExpression);
    }

    public static String getMappedValueExpression(WrappedValueExpression wrappedExpression) {
        String exprString = wrappedExpression.getExpressionString().replace("#{", "").replace("}", "");
        String ret = exprString;
        try {

            Field valueExpression = WrappedValueExpression.class.getDeclaredField("valueExpression");
            valueExpression.setAccessible(true);
            ValueExpressionImpl vei = (ValueExpressionImpl) valueExpression.get(wrappedExpression);
            Field varMapper = ValueExpressionImpl.class.getDeclaredField("varMapper");
            varMapper.setAccessible(true);
            VariableMapperImpl vmi = (VariableMapperImpl) varMapper.get(vei);
            if(vmi != null) {
                String[] components = exprString.split("\\.");
                components[0] = getMappedValueExpression(vmi.resolveVariable(components[0])); 
                ret = "";
                for(int i = 0 ; i < components.length ; i++) {
                    if(i != 0) {
                        ret += ".";
                    }
                    ret += components[i];
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Exception lors du mapping de l'expression EL " + exprString, ex);
        } finally {
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

It would be great to have cleaner versions of this workaround in MyFaces or Mojarra...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in JSF.

It has been filed here with the Mojarra team: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2089 and here with the MyFaces team: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3168. I realize the phrasing of these bug reports is not exactly what you'd expect, but it is the same bug. If you look at the comments:

```
Hi guys,

I just hit this bug again while working on a client's code, and
noticed Manfred had closed it as 'resolved'?

Why was this considered 'resolved'? It's a real problem for me,
stopping me doing things like...

<h:dataTable value="#{companyImport.importFiles}" var="_importFile">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{_importFile.name}:"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <m:metawidget value="#{_importFile.import}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>

...because the m:metawidget cannot 'see' the #{_importFile} var.

Can we please reopen, or at least explain why it is resolved?
```

Neither of these bug reports are making much progress. You may want to comment on them, vote on them, and lend weight to the issue.

Comment: Yep, it seems to be the same bug. I will add a comment to the MyFaces issue too, maybe suggesting a "clean" implementation of the kludge I will provide as a work around in a few minutes.